# Oracle XE crashes when INSERT ALL empty strings into data type CLOB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clob

I've come across this erratic behaviour of `Oracle XE 11.2` on Windows 7 failing when inserting empty strings into a `CLOB` using `INSERT ALL` (as opposed to INSERT), unless that column is the last one of the table, or unless `EMPTY_CLOB()` is used.

**Q1.** Is this a bug of the driver? Why does the trace file say 
Symbol file `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\BIN\ORACLE.SYM` does not match binary, whereas the ORACLE.SYM file is not even in that folder (it's in rdbms), and anyway matches the binary, since it came with that bundle, and Oracle XE works for all the rest besides?

**Q2.** `CLOB` acts as if "after CLOB the deluge" kind of thing, why is it ok if it comes last?

**Q3.** Is there anything I can do to *NOT* have to use `EMPTY_CLOB()`?

*Note that it took me a day and half of research and experiments to figure out I had to use EMPTY_CLOB(). All I was left with first was the crash of Oracle...*

---

I've modelised my problem in the simplest form, for the purpose of submitting it here.
It may appear useless to use `INSERT ALL` for a single line, but my original code features 100-line blocks.

e.g.
-- Experiment #1

```
CREATE TABLE T (
ID NUMBER(7,0),
LONG_LABEL CLOB,
FIELD3 VARCHAR2(30),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

-- Works:

```
INSERT INTO T (ID,LONG_LABEL,FIELD3) VALUES ('1','','');
```

-- Works:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE T;
INSERT ALL INTO T (ID,LONG_LABEL,FIELD3) 
VALUES ('1',EMPTY_CLOB(),'')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

-- but below fails:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE T;
INSERT ALL INTO T (ID,LONG_LABEL,FIELD3) 
VALUES ('1','','')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 10004
Session ID: 99 Serial number: 665

alert.log:

```
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [kokscold()+830] [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [ADDR:0x50] [PC:0x14454ADF0] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []
Errors in file C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace\xe_ora_10004.trc  (incident=2604):
```

(I've pasted the details of that file at the end)

-- but...this works

```
TRUNCATE TABLE T;
INSERT ALL INTO T (ID,LONG_LABEL,FIELD3) 
VALUES ('1','SOME LONG LABEL','SOME VALUE')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

-- Works:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE T;
INSERT ALL INTO T (ID,LONG_LABEL,FIELD3) 
VALUES ('1','','SOME VALUE')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

-- Works:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE T;
INSERT ALL INTO T (ID,LONG_LABEL,FIELD3) 
VALUES ('1','SOME LONG LABEL','')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

-- Experiment #2: SWAP LONG_LABEL & FIELD3

```
DROP TABLE T;

CREATE TABLE T (
ID NUMBER(7,0),
FIELD3 VARCHAR2(30),
LONG_LABEL CLOB,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

-- Works (because CLOB comes last...)

```
INSERT ALL INTO T (ID,FIELD3,LONG_LABEL) 
VALUES ('1','','')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

---

Below are the details of the trace file mentionned earlier.

```
Trace file C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace\xe_ora_10004.trc Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production 
Windows NT Version V6.1 Service Pack 1  
CPU: 2 - type 8664, 2 
Physical Cores Process Affinity    : 0x0x0000000000000000 
Memory (Avail/Total): Ph:1020M/4027M, Ph+PgF:3876M/8053M  
Instance name: xe Redo thread mounted by this instance: 1 
Oracle process number: 25 
Windows thread id: 10004, image: ORACLE.EXE (SHAD)


*** 2016-05-27 14:10:39.004
*** SESSION ID:(99.665) 2016-05-27 14:10:39.004
*** CLIENT ID:() 2016-05-27 14:10:39.004
*** SERVICE NAME:(SYS$USERS) 2016-05-27 14:10:39.004
*** MODULE NAME:(SQL*Plus) 2016-05-27 14:10:39.004
*** ACTION NAME:() 2016-05-27 14:10:39.004
Symbol file C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\BIN\ORACLE.SYM does not match binary.  
Symbol TimeStamp=5386049b, Module TimeStamp=53882d4a are different Exception [type: ACCESS_VIOLATION, UNABLE_TO_READ] [ADDR:0x50] [PC:0x14454ADF0, kokscold()+830] 
Symbol file C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\BIN\ORACLE.SYM does not match binary.
Symbol TimeStamp=5386049b, Module TimeStamp=53882d4a are different Incident 2604 created, dump file:
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\incident\incdir_2604\xe_ora_10004_i2604.trc ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [kokscold()+830] [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [ADDR:0x50] [PC:0x14454ADF0] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []
Symbol file C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\BIN\ORACLE.SYM does not match binary.
Symbol TimeStamp=5386049b, Module TimeStamp=53882d4a are different
```

Comment: See MoS note 460187.1. Or search for similar issues. Or raise a service request, of course.